# How to find number of items dropped based on individual probabilities?

Tags: math, random, sum, probability

My goal is to independently calculate the number of items an enemy would drop after it is killed.  For example, say there are 50 potions each with a 50% chance of being dropped, I'd like to randomly return a number from 0 to 50, based on independent trials.

Currently, this is the code I'm using:

```
int droppedItems(int n, float probability) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x <= n; ++x) {
        if (random() <= probability) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Where probability is a number from 0.0 to 1.0, random() returns 0.0 to 1.0, and n is the maximum number of items to be dropped.  This is in C++ code, however, I'm actually using Visual Basic 6 - so there's no libraries to help with this.

This code works flawlessly.  However, I'd like to optimize this so that if n happens to be 999999, it doesn't take forever (which it currently does).

Comment: Which language are you writing this code in? The sample you posted looks likes like C family pseudocode (unless the `then` was included on accident?)

Comment: @IamChuckB Made some clarifications.

Comment: I updated my answer with code in python that relied on a library. I'll throw some C++ in there too, sans external libraries

Comment: @IamChuckB As I mentioned, I'm using Visual Basic 6, and don't have access to any Python/C++ or other libraries.  I'm more interested in being directed to some code that actually implements this since it's quite a small specific aspect of my project.

Comment: I've updated my answer with my thoughts. The TL;DR version: for what you want it for, implementing a random number generator built on the binomial distribution from scratch, sans libraries, is going to be a prohibitively large PITA. I recommend using your current algo for current algorithms and for larger ones calculating say the first 100 n and then multiplying the result of that by some scaling factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the binomial distribution. [Wiki - Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Ideally, use the libraries for whatever language this pseudocode will be written in. There's no sense in reinventing the wheel unless of course you are trying to learn how to invent a wheel.

Specifically, you'll want something that will let you generate random values given a binomial distribution with a probability of success in any given trial and a number of trials.

**EDIT :**

I went ahead and did this (in python, since that's where I live these days). It relies on the very nice numpy library (hooray, abstraction!):

```
>>>import numpy
>>>numpy.random.binomial(99999,0.5)
49853
>>>numpy.random.binomial(99999,0.5)
50077
```

And, using `timeit.Timer` to check execution time:

```
# timing it across 10,000 iterations for 99,999 items per iteration
>>>timeit.Timer(stmt="numpy.random.binomial(99999,0.5)", setup="import numpy").timeit(10000) 
0.00927[... seconds]
```

**EDIT 2 :**

As it turns out, there isn't a simple way to implement a random number generator based off of the binomial distribution.

There is an algorithm you can implement without library support which will generate random variables from the binomial distribution. [You can view it here as a PDF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.47.8407%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=hm5bUPeREcTj0QHrpYF4&usg=AFQjCNEbbjcA3zKUsq9v0j76nZkzKToRTw)

My guess is that given what you want to use it for (having monsters drop loot in a game), *implementing the algorithm is not worth your time*. There's room for fudge factor here!

I would change your code like this (note: this is not a binomial distribution):

1. Use your current code for small values, say `n` up to `100`.
2. For `n` greater than one hundred, calculate the value of `count` for
   `100` using your current algorithm and then multiply the result by
   `n/100`.

Again, if you really want to figure out how to implement the BTPE algorithm yourself, you can - I think the method I give above wins in the trade off between effort to write and getting "close enough".

Comment: Sampling 100 to avoid the hell of implementing it properly isn't such a bad idea ;).

Answer (score 0):

As @IamChuckB pointed out already, the key word is binomial distribution. When the number of Bernoulli trials (number of items in your example) is large enough, a good approximation is the [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), which is much simpler to calculate and draw numbers from (the exact algorithm is spelled out in the linked Wikipedia article).